# Ignore or eliminate format html <tags> from the text using Regular Expressions in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

We have html response in which need to extract content/text from paragraph html tag and store to compare with xml text like below. In this text, there is  tag in between of the content/text which should be ignored hence trying to achieve this using Regular Expression.

xml content:

```
<p>testing content<italic>text</italic>testing content</p>
```

html content:

```
<p>testing content<i>text</i>testing content</p>
```

For this used:
Reg Exp in Jmeter:

```
<p>(.*)</p)
```

This will fetch entire text and when tried to match with beanshell assertion, it fails since  tag is showing as  in html response.

If tried as:

```
<p>(.*)<i
```

Then also the same issue.

How to ignore/eliminate italic tag using Regular expression of Jmeter, or any other way to achieve the same in Jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [You should not be using Regular Expressions in order to extract data from HTML/XML responses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748)

   JMeter provides [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) which is way more handy for extracting data from XML/HTML responses.

   The relevant [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) query would be as simple as `//p/text()`

   [image]
2. [Using Beanshell is not recommended way of scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), if you need advanced comparison logic consider [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) instead. If you just need to compare 2 variables normal [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) will be more than enough.

   [image]